# Can you use a nexus 7 to develop for an Android phone

Tags: android, smartphone

So I am developing an application for Android OS 4.x really is my main focus. I do not have an Android phone but can get the nexus 7 tablet, but the application is meant to be for a phone (I guess 4.8inch screen, something like an S3) and was wondering how well would it work testing on a Nexus 7.

I am going to use Android Studio to develop the app, not sure if this will be of any value.

I am not looking at this moment in time to make the app go fully main stream etc. It is a project for myself, so I understand if I wanted it too I would have to test on several devices.

Thanks.

Comment: Stack doesn't like these kind of questions but yes it'll work. Just might not look the same.

Comment: Can you use a chainsaw to cut down a tree?

Comment: Yes Ashley just realised by the down votes haha.

Comment: MaxTheG - I'm not sure, shall I post another question on stackoverflow lol.

Answer (score 0):

There are emulators available to develop on in lieu of or in addition to actual hardware.  Genymotion is one I use, and it works well.